# I cannot install phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I get the following page when I redirect to http://localhost/phpmyadmin

[image: link]

I don't understand why this happens, or what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download it [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net), unzip it, and copy the files into the root directory of your development system. Don't install it on a production system.

Answer (score 0):

This answer can easily be found in the PHP manual / documentation or the PHPmyadmin manual / documentation.

You will need a web server to run PHP code. A more famous web server that can be downloaded onto {Assuming you're using windows} your Windows OS is **XAMPP**. There is also: documentation, tutorials, and guides on the web.

Anyways, once you have: downloaded, installed, and configured XAMPP run the web server (XAMPP)

Open your text editor and create a simple template to test your code something such as:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test to see if I'm running PHP </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "Does this echo PHP?"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Open XAMPP and start **Apache**. Open the webpage in your web browser and test to see if the PHP code runs. If the PHP code runs successfully you have installed it correctly. Then open XAMPP once again and run mySQL. If it runs successfully go to your web browser and type **localhost://phpmyadmin**.